# list displays only one item

Tags: list, asp-classic, box

I have two tables - one is a list of employees containing last name, preferred name, and employee id.
My second table has training information tied the employee id.  I want the drop down box to display the distinct trainers by name (not empid) in the dropdown box. Currently only one trainer is listed in the box (there are 3 distinct ids).

```
 <%
    strSQL = "SELECT distinct TrainerEmpID FROM TrainingEvaluation  ;"
    Set adoCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    adoCon.Open "DSN=testconsol"
    Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.Open strSQL, adoCon
    qtid=rs("TrainerEmpID")



        %>




<table  width="700" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
    <tr height="9"></tr>
  <tr>
          <td><font face="sans-serif">Trainer:&nbsp;
            <%     strSQL = "SELECT * FROM EmployeeList WHERE EmpID= " & qtid & "   ;"
                Set adoCon4 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
                adoCon4.Open "DSN=testconsol"
                Set rs4 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
                rs4.Open strSQL, adoCon4%>
<Select Name="TLName" size="1">
<%While Not rs4.EOF   %>
<option value="<%= rs4("LastName") %>"><%= rs4("LastName") %>,&nbsp;<%= rs4("PreferredName") %>    </option>
<%
rs4.MoveNext
Wend
    rs4.Close
    Set rs4 = Nothing
    Set adoCon4 = Nothing
%>


</Select>
    </td></font>
```

Thanks for any help (I am new to this).

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is off: you are using only the first ID.

You can do it all with a single SQL query:

```
<table  width="700" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
    <tr height="9"></tr>
  <tr>
          <td><font face="sans-serif">Trainer:&nbsp;
<Select Name="TLName" size="1">
<%
    strSQL = "SELECT distinct e.LastName, e.PreferredName  FROM TrainingEvaluation t Inner Join EmployeeList e On t.TrainerEmpID=e.EmpID"
    Set adoCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    adoCon.Open "DSN=testconsol"
    Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    objRS.Open strSQL, adoCon
    Do Until objRS.EOF %>
       <option value="<%= objRS("LastName") %>"><%= objRS("LastName") %>,&nbsp;<%= objRS("PreferredName") %>    </option>
<%
         objRS.MoveNext
    Loop
    objRS.Close
    Set objRS = Nothing
    adoCon.Close
    Set adoCon = Nothing
%>
</Select>
</td></font>
```